# I'm trying to put a marker in ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to put a marker in ArrayList in this way:

First I declare in the class MainActivity:

```
public ArrayList<Marker> myList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

After starting my program marks the first point and hides it:

```
        if (myList.get(0)==null)
 {
     MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
             .position(latLng)
             .visible(false)
     myList.add(0, mMap.addMarker(options));
}
```

then I write the next marker button is pressed

```
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
    public void onClick(View view) 
{
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)


    if (myList.get(0) != null)
    {

                        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)                        
                        myList.add(1,mMap.addMarker(options));

    }
    else if (myList.get(0) != null && (myList.get(1) != null))
    {                      
                        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                       .position(latLng)                                        
                        myList.add(2,mMap.addMarker(options));        
    }
```

And application gets a crash at the start ...
When instead of the list was the tab[], the program will work

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: Add Logcat, with error.

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: please point out the line where you get the exception....

Comment: It means you are trying `myList.get(0)` or equivalent on an empty list. Please note that it’s not enough to test that `myList.get(0)` is not null since the call to the `get()` method is enough that the error happens. Instead try something like `if (! myList.isEmpty())` and/or `if (myList.size() >= 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Before getting the index 0 of your array, check if it's not empty.

```
if (!myList.isEmpty())
{
 if (myList.get(0)==null)
  {
     //do your thing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those null checks are unnecessary, just use `List.add(Object o)` function, that doesn't take index as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I bet this line is causing the crash:

`myList.add(1,mMap.addMarker(options))`

If `myList` is empty, calling `myList.add(foo, 1)` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, causing your app to crash. The reason for this is that arrays are 0-indexed, meaning that the first value is at index 0. It may sound counter-intuitive, but adding something to an empty list's index 1 is actually trying to set its second element.

Overall, your code is very weirdly structured. The non-indexed version of `List.add(Object o)` adds an item to the end of the list, so you can just use that in your `OnClickListener`.